# TypeORM select alias of column name

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

```
this.sampleRepo.find(
  {
    order: {
      id: "DESC"
    },
    select: ['id','group']
  }
);
```

this returns the `id` and `group` as expected, but how to return `id` as `user_id` ?
and also how to select distinct values from group?

Comment: 1) id as user_id: For now you can't or at least the value is mapped as the column name of the Entity class. See [@Column](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/column) decorator *name* option.

Comment: i saw the column name option but was thinking what to do if you need to send two different name in two different api, for example in api A , i wan to send id as userid, in api B , i want to send id as id. Column name decorator will not help here.

Comment: 2) You must use **QueryBuilder**. There is an open issue, see [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5163), to add distinct for entity manager find options.

Comment: You want a remap? To do so: 1) Find all entities in an array 2) [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to rename the identification -> Note this is a really bad procedure since it has O(n) complexity and reduce the correct semantic to you api. I strongly suggest to choose one identifier to avoid efficiency problem and many more future issues.

Comment: For production identifier will be one, i'm just asking to learn how to do things if needed.

Comment: What is the standard way of doing this through query builder?

Comment: There is no standard de facto, it depend on you. For me, I always try to use find options but it's not powerful as querybuilder. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666465/typeorm-queryrunner-select-distinct).

Comment: For the first question, create an entity that is the same except for user_id and remap using map function on array the values. Remember, this is not good, keep you API as simple and coincise as possible.

Comment: this.sampleRepo.createQueryBuilder('user')
        .where ('user.id != 0')
        .select(['user.id','user.groups'])
        .orderBy("user.groups", "ASC")
        .distinct(true)
        .getRawMany();

When i use this, the query works, when i use distinctOn ['user.groups'], it doesnt work, am i missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add an alias in you select string, e.g.:

```
select: ['id AS user_id','group AS user_group']
```

---

If the previous option didn't work, it should work in queryBuilder:

```
this.sampleRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .orderBy('user.id', 'DESC')
      .select(['id AS user_id','group AS user_group'])
      .getRawMany() // or .getMany()
```

---

I've made smth as you need with one of my examples [(last one here)](https://github.com/olshansky/typeorm-holes-demo/blob/master/src/app.service.ts#L38) but wrote this *(upd. fixed with getRawMany and distinct)*:

```
getMany(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.userRepo.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where({ username: 'breckhouse0' })
      .select(['DISTINCT (user.username) AS user_name', 'user.id AS user_id'])
      .getRawMany();
  }
```

and this works as you expect - [results](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2020/07/06/0027/2438/1833350/50/8df8230b12.jpg)

Comment: Now it works with query builder, but for entity manager , it doesn't work.
Please add the distinct option in the query with username column, ill accept the answer.

Comment: Ive accepted the answer , can you please help another point, how to do a query in find method  , like i want to do a query where user id will be 1 or 2, for this i was giving return this.userRepository.find(
            {
                where  : {
   id: In ["1","2"]
} 
            }
        );

but its not working, my objective is to get all the user with id 1 or 2.

Comment: You missed round brackets `In()` - `return this.userRepository.find( { where : { id: In(["1","2"]) } } )`

Comment: I got result with ``getRawMany()`` but not with ``getMany()``

Comment: I got result with `getRawMany()` but not with `getMany()`

Comment: Me too. All's good in raw via `getRawMany()` but aliases seems not to be binded in entities.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give same column name and format

```
.select("id", "user_id")
.addSelect("group", "user_group")
```

Below will convert column name in Capital letter after response

```
select: ['id AS user_id','group AS user_group']
```