# How to map joined table column to an entity's field in TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

There are two entities as follow:

```
// user.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @RelationId((user: User) => user.group)
  groupId: number;

  @Column()
  fullName: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  passwordHash: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Group, group => group.users)
  @JoinColumn()
  group: Group;

  isOwner: boolean;
}
```

```
// group.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Group extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isOwner: boolean;

  @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.group)
  users: User[];
}
```

I'd like to map the `isOwner` value of `Group` to `isOwner` of `User`

I tried:

```
  async findOneById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return await User.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndMapOne('user.isOwner', 'user.group', 'group')
      .select(['user.id', 'user.fullName', 'user.email', 'group.isOwner'])
      .getOne();
  }
```

the result was:

[image]

It is possible to achieve that by using `@AfterLoad()` or with JS or with raw query.

#### BUT

Is it possible to implement that using the orm on the query level?

Answer (score 2):

Something like that could be as a solution:

```
  findOneById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return User.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndMapOne('user.isOwner', 'user.group', 'group')
      .select(['user.id', 'user.fullName', 'user.email', 'group.isOwner AS user.isOwner']) // or probably 'group.isOwner AS user_isOwner'
      .getOne();
  }
```

---

And you could look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761311/8368358), hope it would be helpful